# How can I see the description of a request after a topic is created from it?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Requests have a description which often gives some details on the requested topic. After the topic is created, I couldn't find a way to read this description any longer. Am I missing something here? If not, can we please add this feature?

**Edit:** The reason I ask this is that I recently found a request with specific requirements for the requested examples, but after the first example was created, I cannot even check if these requirements are actually fulfilled. Also others which didn't read the original request have simply no knowledge that these requirements existed in the first place.