# Fix the UI for initiating a Docs edit so improvement requests are not erroneously handled

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Most of my improvement requests are "handled" erroneously thanks to what I hope is a UI oversight.

Here's the usual pattern:

1. Helpful user arrives at a Topic
2. They have a look at improvement requests
3. They think "Hey, I have some ideas for edits too"
4. They think "And here's this bright blue 'edit' button!"
5. They edit as they see fit, typically *not* handling the requests
6. Improvement requests all disappear

As a result, improvement requests are rarely addressed in my tag, instead being "handled" almost at random. Here's the UI I'm referring to. Assuming you have had a look at the improvement requests, the most obvious way to edit the Topic or Example is this the blue button below:

[image]

(Please ignore the substance of these requests. I just mean to illustrate the UI.)

And after you click it, SO quietly assumes that you are attempting to handle all of the improvement requests with this edit, and checks the box next to every request for you:

[image]

In my experience, it is much more common that the editor is attempting to handle *none of the improvement requests*. And why should we assume otherwise? They clicked an "Edit Example" button, not a "Resolve everyone's issues with this Example" button.

**Request/proposal**: Change the text on that button. Leave those boxes unchecked by default. Maybe put another "Edit" button in the right pane, below the "Topic Outline."

**Some concrete examples**:

- [Here, I was berating the editors](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/104206) for subsetting mixed tabular data as if it was a matrix ... which the editor did not have any intention of addressing. As a result, I had to re-post my request, and will have to do so again and again after every edit anyone makes. I've had this experience on a few other examples as well.
- Going beyond examples, I have had the same experience with Topic Requests. [I requested a "Randomization" topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/topic-requests/2206) with several features. Someone "handled" it by addressing the first one, making all record of the others disappear, so [I had to re-post it](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/topic-requests/2290). This issue was [brought up in July](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328861/1191259), too.

Maybe the discussion section can somehow do a better job of not destroying improvement and topic requests, but I'm posting this to clarify some of the most infuriating features of the current system.

Answer (score 1):

> And why should we assume otherwise? They clicked an "Edit Example" button, not a "Resolve everyone's issues with this Example" button.

Because the button is in the improvement request section... or such is the theory. I agree that right now the buttons are drawing far too much attention. I'll get with the team to see how we could clarify this behaviour. Maybe something along the lines of a "handle these requests" link/button that brings up the list of available actions. We'll see.

Thanks for the detailed write-up!